# How can I run Windows Defender while running a second anti-virus in Windows?

Tags: windows, windows-8, anti-virus, windows-defender

I want to run a Windows Defender scan while running an antivirus scan. In my case I am using Trend Micro OfficeScan Antivirus with  Windows.

Currently Windows will close and disable Windows defender if I start up another antivirus.

The reason why I want to do this is because I get laptops that have been infested and its my job to clean them for viruses. Normally I just started up a Virus scan and a Windows Defender scan. An hour later they both would be done.

Windows Defender sometimes finds things that my Antivirus doesn't. Its a peace of mind issue, it looks good on the IT reports.

Comment: Running two anti-virus security software programs has never been a good idea.  Why do you want to run both at the sametime?  They will conflict with one another if you manage to figure out a way around the built in protections to prevent you from doing exactly this.

Comment: Telling your higher ups that you ran two scans looks better than saying I have run one. I will only be making this change on my computer that I use to scan the department HDDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 now has a feature where you can continue to use Windows defender when you have an anti-virus program installed. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to run Windows Defender scan, you must disable you other installed antivirus for that moment.  Once the scan from Windows defender has finished scanning, you can start up another antivirus and continue scanning with that.  I think, it is a good initiative by Windows 8 to disable Windows defender, if it finds another antivirus, as in case of Windows 7, we have to manually take care of it, as keeping two antivirus software together on a machine is not advisable.

Comment: ugh what a hassle. There has to be a way around it. I know its not advisable and serves little utility. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to do that, run one or the other. When you install a 3rd party antivirus it disables Windows Defender.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of running two Anti viruses, I would suggest running an antimalware program  real time at the same time as your anti virus. They work beautifully together and don't conflict with each other. Another layer of security is to make sure that you have a Firewall enabled.

Windows has one and some other companies do too. An anti virus program + antimalware + a Firewall should protect you from 99+% of the issues.